# Parse complex TypeName from a String in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, types

From a `CompactFramework`, I got a `TypeString` which can be a *complex* type, meaning it can use *generics, arrays*, etc. That means it can look like `Sytem.Tuple’1[[Sytem.String, mscorlib]]`. Problem is, I can not use `Type.GetType` because the `assemblys` in the `Typestring` may be wrong or not present.
Is there a lib which parses the string, and returns a type by searching all types in `appdomain` for the right one?

Comment: That would not work. Assemblynames may be wrong

Comment: if you look exactly, Type.parse is in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now found no Code, but solved using this:

```
public static class TypeHelper
{
    public static Type GetTypeFromString(string typeString)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        return ParseInternal(typeString, ref pos);
    }

    private static Type ParseInternal(string name, ref int pos)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<Type> genericParameters = null;
        int arrayDimensions = 0;
        bool ignore = false;

        while (pos < name.Length)
        {
            char c = name[pos++];
            switch (c)
            {
                case ',':
                    {
                        if (arrayDimensions > 0)
                            arrayDimensions++;
                        else
                            ignore = true;

                        break;
                    }
                case '[':
                    {
                        if (name[pos] == '[')
                        {
                            if (genericParameters == null)
                                genericParameters = new List<Type>();
                            pos++;
                            genericParameters.Add(ParseInternal(name, ref pos));
                        }
                        else if (genericParameters!=null)
                            genericParameters.Add(ParseInternal(name, ref pos));
                        else
                            arrayDimensions++;
                        break;
                    }
                case ']':
                    {
                        var currentName = sb.ToString();
                        var type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == currentName);
                        if (name.Length > pos && name[pos] == ']')
                        {
                            pos++;
                        }
                        if (genericParameters != null)
                        {
                            return type.MakeGenericType(genericParameters.ToArray());
                        }
                        else if (arrayDimensions != 0)
                        {
                            return type.MakeArrayType(arrayDimensions);
                        }
                        return type;
                    }
                default:
                    if (!ignore)
                        sb.Append(c);
                    continue;
            }
        }
        {
            var currentName = sb.ToString();
            var type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == currentName);
            if (genericParameters != null)
            {
                return type.MakeGenericType(genericParameters.ToArray());
            }
            else if (arrayDimensions != 0)
            {
                return type.MakeArrayType(arrayDimensions);
            }
            return type;
        }
    }
}
```